# NFSv2 on Fedora 38

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs

I have the problem with NFS file system. Client could not connect to the server but the latter gets the request and grants access to the client. The configuration is the following.

**NFS Server**

- Fedora Linux 38
- Folder `/home/user/nfs/` with mod 0777
- IP address is `193.232.173.2`
- `/etc/export` content:

  ```
  /home/user/nfs 193.232.173.251(rw,sync,no_acl,insecure,no_root_squash)
  ```

**NFS Client**

- Diskless UNIX-based OS (oc2000, also known as RT OS BAGET, not UNIX itself but just UNIX-based)
- IP address is `193.232.173.251`
- NFS is mounted via program code with the following command line:

  ```shell
  mount -t nfs -o rsize=4096,wsize=4096 193.232.173.2:/home/user/nfs /nfs
  ```

No other command line options are available

**Result**

NFS is mounted but client cannot read/write (also via program code). I found out that NFS server hadn't supported version 2 of NFS and client worked ONLY with NFSv2.

I built Linux kernel (version 6.6.8) with NFSv2 support, but there was no connection. Client only sends the command above and then nothing happens.

System journal contains the following log:

```
rpc.mountd authenticated mount request from 193.232.173.251:1023 for /home/user/nfs (/home/user/nfs)
rpc.mountd granted access to /home/user/nfs for 193.232.173.251
rpc.mountd nfsd_fh: found 0x55f566742490 path /home/user/nfs
rpc.mountd nfsd_fh: inbuf '193.232.173.251 4 \x408a0300938534b9'
```

- I tried combinations of client options in `/etc/export` – didn't help.
- I tried to toggle settings in `/etc/nfs.conf` – didn't help too.
- `[nfsd]` section of `/etc/nfs.conf` is the following:

  ```ini
  debug=1
  udp=on
  tcp=on
  vers2=y
  vers3=y
  vers4=n
  vers4.0=n
  vers4.1=n
  vers4.2=n
  rdma=y
  rdma-port=20049
  ```

I even looked Linux source code up to find message given above – with no result.

Could you please help me? What else should I do to make client and server work by NFS?

UPD. Below is output of rpcinfo -p

```
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100024    1   udp  44697  status
    100024    1   tcp  37411  status
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  60925  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  60925  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  60925  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  46315  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  46315  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  46315  nlockmgr
```

Comment: First, please run `rpcinfo -p` on your NFS Server system and post the results into your question. (Not here in the comments.) You'll want to select the text and then use the `{}` button to mark it up as program text

Comment: It is likely to help if you actually name the operating system of the client. People stand a fair chance of remembering the oddities of their historic operating systems, but only if they know what they're up against. "not UNIX itself but just UNIX-based" is kind of unhelpful. Especially since the only nfs v2-only-but-not-actually-unix candidate that comes to mind would be Eunice, but that should have had differently-looking `mount` invocations, so this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Should that be `/etc/exports` ? Maybe just a typo in your question ... (although it is mentioned a few times)

Comment: OK, I will add `rpcinfo -p` result later, the operating system of the client is _oc2000_, also known as RT OS BAGET

Comment: Lovely, thank you. If it doesn't have the `rpcinfo` command you can run it on another machine, `rpcinfo -p {remoteHost}`, replacing `{remoteHost}` with the name or address of your NFS Server system

Comment: Do you_need_ NFSv2 for the client? That isn't enabled out of the box in Fedora Linux at the kernel level, (and hasn't been for a while). https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/nfs-v2-mounting/86059

Comment: @mattdm that looks really useful!

Comment: @mattdm I have no choice. NFSv2 is the only available feature for the client, enabling NFSv4 is impossible on its side

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone, the problem has been solved in an original way. I downgraded to Fedora 22 (according to the documentation on this client machine), configured RPC and NFS… and it works! Client does connect to the server and even reads and writes files!

Answer (score -2):

on the NFS-server (Fedora 38 you said) **for troubleshooting** you will want to

- turn off SELINUX, either manually each time after boot by `setenforce 0` or modifying `/etc/selinux/config` and set to `permissive`
- turn off the firewall
- really check `/etc/nfs.conf` for correct syntax everywhere, with all `vers<num> = y`

First thing that comes to mind is modern NFSv4 is all on one single port... 2049.  NFSv3 was on port 111, in addition to other ports for `mountd`, `statd`, `lockd`, `nfsd`, `sm-notify`.  You will see this as commented out (now) in `/etc/nfs.conf` for nfsv4 in Fedora38.  For starters to allow a current linux distro which is NFSv4 by default to fall back to NFSv2 you will need to make sure your nfs-server is listening  on the correct ports (and not firewalling them) for everything for which your nfsv2 client is talking on.

Comment: selinux does not need to be off

Comment: You really shouldn't turn off the firewall. That's just unnecessary. You need the nfs and idmapper ports, and the ports specified in the mount. You wouldn't say "to get a piano into your house, you should removed all window panes"; you need to open the door, so open the door. [Relatively authoritative source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config)

Comment: see updated text in bold.  I didn't think I needed to explicitly state that, thought it would have come across.